# Using intel xdk with meteor js

Tags: javascript, cordova, meteor, intel, intel-xdk

I am trying to create mobile apps using intel xdk using meteor js. I have tried using the meteor commands through the terminal but i keep getting "Fetching plugin "org.apache.cordova.console@0.2.10" via plugin registry" but it never completes and I cannot move on.

I would also like to use intel xdk to access cordova and intel apis.

Comment: There's an issue with the cordova repository & someone deleted the older `org.apache.cordova.console` packages. Hopefully they're back soon you can then retry.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to figure something out and now I think cordova packages are back online!